# Autofixture and WebApi Controller

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, xunit, autofixture

I am using AutoFixture to try to test my controllers for a WebApi site.  I am using the AutoData feature with Moq as noted on [Ploeh's blog](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheoriesWithAutoFixture.aspx).

My controller takes an IDepartmentManager in the constructor.  Here is my test:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void GetCallsManagerCorrectly(
    [Frozen]Mock<IDepartmentManager> departmentManagerMock,
    DepartmentsController sut)
{
    // Fixture setup
    // Exercise system
    sut.Get();
    // Verify outcome
    departmentManagerMock.Verify(d => d.GetAllDepartments(), Times.Exactly(1));
    // Teardown
}
```

When I run this test it fails with the following:

> GetCallsManagerCorrectly has failed:
>   System.InvalidOperationException : An exception was thrown while
>   getting data for theory
>   Provision.Tests.WebApiControllerTests.DepartmentControllerTests.GetCallsManagerCorrectly:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Only
>   'http' and 'https' schemes are allowed.   Parameter name: value   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage.set_RequestUri(Uri value)

First of all, is this still a valid and recommended way to write these tests?  I love how small it makes everything.

Secondly, what should I do to fix this?  If I change my test to this:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void GetCallsManagerCorrectly(
    [Frozen]Mock<IDepartmentManager> departmentManagerMock)
{
    // Fixture setup
    DepartmentsController sut =
        new DepartmentsController(departmentManagerMock.Object);
    // Exercise system
    sut.Get();
    // Verify outcome
    departmentManagerMock.Verify(d => d.GetAllDepartments(), Times.Exactly(1));
    // Teardown
}
```

it passes, but then I lose the ability to have the controller built up automatically and still be ok if I add parameters to the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely the recommended way to write tests with AutoFixture. The issue is pretty easy to fix.

Instead of implementing the [AutoMoqData] attribute as described in the blog post, I'd recommend creating a slightly different attribute and Customization - a set that basically will act as a set of conventions for an entire unit test project. I always do this, and I always go to great lengths to have only a single set of conventions for a single unit test project. A single set of conventions help me keep my tests (and the [SUT](http://xunitpatterns.com/SUT.html)s) consistent.

```
public class AutoMyWebApiDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMyWebApiDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new MyWebApiCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

The MyWebApiCustomization could be defined like this:

```
public class MyWebApiCustomization : CompositeCustomization
{
    public MyWebApiCustomization()
        : base(
            new HttpSchemeCustomization(),
            new AutoMoqCustomization(),
        )
    {
    }

    private class HttpSchemeCustomization : ICustomization
    {
        public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
        {
            fixture.Inject(new UriScheme("http"));
        }
    }
}
```

Note the additional HttpSchemeCustomization class - that should do the trick.

Please note that [the order of Customizations matters](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/31/TheOrderOfAutoFixtureCustomizationsMatter.aspx).

Comment: @BrianMcCord and others Pretty sure the `HttpSchemeCustomization` above is now intrinsic in AF V3+.